Bulk Update Activity Stage
I am trying to update a list of outstanding Activities that have not been updated on Civi. Is there a way to do them all in one go and not do them all individually? Want to change them over to complete

You can use searchkit and get the list of activity you want to update and from the actions drop down choose Bulk update option
